# Почему при переходе по ссылке появляется белый экран?

Tags: php, битрикс

Работаю с Bitrix настроил ЧПУ для вывода новостей но при переходе по ссылке белый экран,почему я не знаю. Дома такой же вариант работает. Логи ничего не говоря Помогите

Comment: если логи пустые  - попробуйте включить вывод ошибок 
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

Comment: Подскажи куда прописать эти строчки?

Comment: Короче говоря вывел ошибки проблемы не нашёл

Comment: не используйте тяжелblе фона, и всего по минимуму, сейчас в моде минималистичность

Comment: @АлександрСтарцев если ошибки теперь отображаются покажите их нам или сами прочитайте в чем проблема.
исклено что при подобном поведении логи не падают в error.log или на экран

Answer (score 1):

В настройках "Главного модуля" включите вывод всех ошибок и предупреждений: `/bitrix/admin/settings.php?lang=ru&mid=main&mid_menu=1`

Белый экран -- это однозначно ошибка на стороне сервера, но вот какая -- покажет вывод ошибок.

И для адекватной помощи, конечно, не помешал бы скриншот, как именно вы настроили ЧПУ.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/BuXxBSTZjZtnZ
Файл index.php с компонентом лежит в корне сайта в папке news

Comment: Причём такое же дерьмо и с 404

Comment: Компонент, вообще говоря можно и не указывать.
Возможно, ошибка в `/news/index.php`

Вот эти статьи читали?

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/general/urlrewrite.php

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=34&LESSON_ID=3579

Помогло ли включение вывода всех ошибок и предупреждений?

Comment: Я нашёл свой косяк прошу прощения за беспокойство. Причина была в том, что там был неправильно настроен ЧПУ для умного фильтра, что и отразилось.